# jQuery UI and CodeIgniter/Boilerplate... Dialog Modal not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, html5boilerplate

I am trying to use the jQuery UI to bring up a dialog modal. I am using it in conjuction with CodeIgniter and HTML5Boilerplate.

In a normal, blank html page, I can get the dialog code to work (just importing the css and jquery scripts from google.

In the CodeIgniter view, it doesn't work. The entire output is here: http://pastebin.com/5e2PfE14

The script that I am using, in my scripts.js file is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

The imports are working fine, so what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: "I believe that the imports are working fine." Can you definitely confirm this (Assuming you mean the JS and CSS)?

Comment: The imports are working. I used the jQuery Getting Started guide, located here: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started and successfully used the datePicker widget. So, I believe that confirms that jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-css and my scripts.js file are all imported properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include all javascript and css files by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('css/style.css'); ?>" />` and if you use apache mod_rewrite for removing index.php check rules (maybe something disallow your javascript, css or images). Also check in your config file whether $config['base_url'] is set .